# Is there a way to loop through custom object properties in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

So I made an interface that looks like this:

```
export interface MyInput {
    disabled?: boolean,
    type: 'text' | 'email' | 'password' | 'number',
    label?: string,
    placeholder?: string,
    helpText?: string
}
```

I am making a component in Angular, which based on given values draws specific input field. Component code looks like this:

```
export class BasicInputsComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() options: MyInput = {
    type: 'text',
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (const key in this.options) {
      console.log(this.options[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

My for-in loop doesn't work it gives me this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'MyInput'. No index signature
> with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MyInput'.ts(7053)

What can I do to get keys and their relative values in my object dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... well, for example  type up the `key` in the iteration (other ways possible too) :

```js
class Tester {
  options: MyInput = {
    type: 'text',
  }

  test() {
    for (const key in this.options) {
      console.log(this.options[key as keyof MyInput]);
    }
  }

 testNoTyping() { Object.entries(this.options).forEach(([key, val]) => console.log({ [key]: val })) }

}
```

Comment: That's what I wanted, thanks a lot ❤